# Disabling kextcache on 10.5.8 and 10.6.3

Tags: macos, kernel, launchd, kernel-extension

We use [Radmind](http://www.radmind.org) to manage our Mac OS X loadsets and, as such, often run into difficulty when new OS releases come out due to, among other things, updated kernel extensions. The workflow in the past (OS revisions <= 10.4) was to delete the kernel extension cache, update the extensions, and then reboot. That worked just fine, as the system would re-create missing caches on boot. In Leopard, you need to delete the caches *after* replacing the kernel extensions with their new versions, as the system will automatically start creating them when you replace them; the only way to ensure that you don't have invalid extensions cached is to delete the cache before rebooting.

I'm looking for a way to prevent the kernel extensions cache from being re-created until the next reboot. If you modify the contents of `/System/Library/Extensions/`, `kextcache` will start up automatically. I've looked through `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and other places, but I can't find whatever it is that's starting `kextcache`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jeff, are you trying to run servers here?  if so, this might be better suited to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).  (please don't crosspost; the question can be migrated if necessary.)

Comment: No, this is referring to the client OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after delving into some of Apple's open-source code, I have solved this issue (at least for Snow Leopard). By issuing the following command:

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.kextd.plist
```

You can update kernel extensions, delete their cache file(s), and reboot; the extension caches will be re-created at boot time. I still need to test this for Leopard, but for Snow Leopard it works just fine.